# Why I can't delete the database?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I'm getting Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: syntax error at or near "$1" POSITION: 25'

```
public async Task Delete(string dbName) { 
    using(var connection = GetNewConnection()) { 
    connection.Open();
        using(var command = new NpgsqlCommand("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS @dbName;", connection)) {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbName", dbName);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } 
    }
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use parameters with `DROP TABLE`.

Comment: And make sure you’re connected to a different database, you can’t drop the database you’re connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comment, DDL statements such as `DROP DATABASE` cannot be used with parameters.